# Why ker f defines only in homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why kernel of any map can only be defined in group homomorphism, why can't we define it on simple map. Just simply clarify my query.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, and from the downvotes I gather that others don't understand either. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If $f:X \to Y$ is any map and if $y_0 \in Y \neq \varnothing$, we could define $\text{ker}_{y_0}(f) := f^{-1}(\{y_0\})$… but this is useless. In algebra, $\text{ker}(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is useful because it is a normal subgroup/ideal of your algebraic structure (provided that $f$ is a morphism).

Comment: I am simply asking what my teacher says that kernel of map is only defined if map is homomorphism. Why? Why not in simple maps.

Comment: You *could* define it for general maps between groups, but it is not a useful concept if the map isn't a homomorphism. (Well, you could cook up an example where it might be useful, but it is not *generally* useful, and so it is better not to make the definition apply to the general case.)

Comment: Means it just have matter of importance no specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking: *Why is it important that $f$ be a homomorphism when defining its kernel?*

If $f \colon G \to H$ is any map between groups, you *could* call the inverse image of the identity in $H$ the “kernel” of $f$.  But it's only when $f$ is a homomorphism that $\ker f$ is a subgroup.  If it weren't a subgroup, it wouldn't be very useful in algebraic terms.

For instance (since you asked for an example), let $f\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2 - 4$.  The “kernel” of this map would be $\left\{-2,2\right\}$.  But this isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$; it's not closed under addition.

Comment: It would even be confusing, because the mathematical audience will only associated the concept of kernels with homomorphisms. So when someone mentions the kernel of a map that *isn't* a homomorphism, the mathematicians' first reaction will be: wait, what?

Comment: Sir can u explain briefly why necessary to be homomorphism, it will be more helpful if  u give example.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Do you mean like how some authors use the word *ring* to mean *ring with unit* and some don't? :-) *cough* serge lang *cough*

Comment: Thnx for ASN sir

Comment: @Ashu5765449: I don't know what ASN means, but you are welcome.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Um, no, I wasn't thinking of that, but that prompted me to read about the [history of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#History) on wikipedia. The subsection on the multiplicative identity makes for some fascinating reading. In particular, Lang is not an isolated case!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Lang has some more unconventional conventions, but they escape me at the moment.

Comment: Sorry sir I was writing ans.